# Why Gatsby.js doesn't prerender the blog starter?

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I want to move my Wordpress blog to staticaly generated one.I've decided to use Gatsby.js, but have problems with lack of content on prerendered pages.
I start with blog starter:

```sh
gatsby new gatsbyBlog https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog
cd gatsbyBlog
```

then i build a project:

```
gatsby build
```

When I look into generated index.html HTML I see no posts in the body, all i can see is:

```
<noscript id="gatsby-noscript">This app works best with JavaScript enabled.</noscript>
```

I need my blog to be crawlable without JS.

I would expect a body HTML code of different pages to contain the content of the page. Just like on this Gatsby website: 
https://snipcart.github.io/gatsby-pwa-demo/all-about-weapons

I expected it would be available out of the box. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and `gatsby build` the project. For me all the content is there. The build is located in `gatsbyBlog/public/index.html`. Try to access the file manually via the file system and open in a text editor, not in the browser. The html code should be there.

Gatsby does a lot of code splitting and needs javascript to put together the actual html code for the browser. Maybe a browser plugin intercepted loading the rest of the html because of the script tags? I know that I got a lot of these messages when I used stuff like NoScript.

Answer (score 0):

Also, see if the Gatsby offline plugin is enabled. If so, I noticed that on a soft reload or via the back button of the browser, a different, js-based version of the index page is loaded. This might be what you are seeing.